# Error while installing orange

Tags: ubuntu

I have already installed anaconda. I have updated my python to latest as well. But when I try to install orange it gives me the following error:

```
Collecting orange3
  Using cached Orange3-3.5.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Orange requires Python >= 3.4

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zWUMVm/orange3/
```

Please tell how I can solve it

Comment: What does `python --version` say?

Comment: What exactly are you running to install it?

Comment: @slhck - They are attempting to install [Orange3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Orange3) it's a Python package

Comment: @Ramhound I know, I was asking which exact command they ran.

Comment: I thought you were asking, "what exactly are you trying to install", oops

Comment: @8bittree It says python 2.7 :D. I tried upgrading it just now but it doesn't upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 is not backwards compatible with Python 2, thus, a Python 2 installation will not be automatically updated to Python 3.

There are a couple things you could do:

1. Use the Python 2 version of packages. Here's [orange](https://orange.biolab.si/orange2/) for Python 2.
2. Install Python 3. This is the [`python3`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/python3) package in the Ubuntu repositories, and I believe can be used alongside Python 2, with the `python` executable running Python 2, and the `python3` executable running Python 3.

You should also make sure other Python packages (such as Anaconda) you're using match the version of Python you decide to use.